# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'start') vue 3 in vuex

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import 'firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css'

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

const auth = {
  context: null,
  uiConfig: null,
  ui: null,

  init(context) {
    this.context = context;

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    this.uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: '/',
      signInOptions: [
   
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      ]
    }
    this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.context.$store.dispatch('user/setCurrentUser')

      let requireAuth = this.context.$route.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireAuth)
      let guestOnly = this.context.$route.matched.some(record => record.meta.guestOnly)

      if(requireAuth && !user) this.context.$router.push('/auth/login')
      else if (guestOnly && user) this.context.$router.push('/')
    });
  },
  authForm(container) {
    
    console.log(this.ui);

    this.ui.start(container, this.uiConfig);
  },
  user() {
    return this.context ? firebase.auth().currentUser : null;
  },
  logout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
}

export default auth;
```

```
     "firebase": "^9.14.0",
        "firebaseui": "^6.0.2",
```

```
     "firebase": "^9.14.0",
        "firebaseui": "^6.0.2",
```

here i am using Firebase UI.but i get error this.ui.start(container, this.uiConfig) this line .what the problem of ui start and how to solve this problem?

here i am using Firebase UI.but i get error this.ui.start(container, this.uiConfig) this line .what the problem of ui start and how to solve this problem?

Comment: `auth.authForm()` is called when its `ui` is `null`. You probably want to call it after `auth.init()`.